# Writing specific variable to .txt or .mat with Dymola

Tags: string, stream, modelica, dymola

I am in need of a way to write a specific variable from a simulation to either .txt or .mat.

The use of:

```
Streams.print(Modelica.Math.Vector.toString(resultVector),"filename");
```

results in wrong data as in no acordance when compared to the export of the variable over the simulation tab. The values in the .txt file are completly different with no pattern visible.

Comment: Do you need to write this during the simulation or would post-processing the result-file be acceptable? If you do it during simulation you probably would need to use `when sample(...)` to force the output in the correct order.

Comment: Yes is Acceptable but i dont want to be bound to matlab. Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would `Modelica.Utilities.Streams.writeRealMatrix` do what you need?

For me

```
Modelica.Utilities.Streams.writeRealMatrix(
  fileName="C:/temp/test.mat", 
  matrixName="testMatrix", 
  matrix=[1,2;4,5], 
  append=false, 
  format="7")
```

resulted in the expected .mat file.

For being able to write a variable in the `.mat` file, you will have to convert your variable to a (two-dimensional) matrix - if it isn't already one. This can be accomplished by converting a scalar or vector using square brackets. This would give `matrix=[1]` for a scalar or `matrix=[{1,2,3,4}]` for a vector. Using `matrix=1` or `matrix={1,2,3,4}` will trow an error.

Comment: This resulted in very slow computation! I will try this again tomorrow tho.

Comment: You could also give `DymolaCommands.MatrixIO.writeMatrix` a try or use the `DataFiles` library, which is included in the Dymola standard installation.

Comment: where can i find documentation for this library online?

Comment: I think nowhere. There is some documentation if you open the classes in Dymola.

Answer (score 2):

Since post-processing would be acceptable, there are some options available:

Dymola includes the tool `alist`:

```
alist -e var1 [-e var2 ...] inputFile outputFile

export data for var... as comma-separated values, suitable
for importing into Microsoft Excel.

Options: -a  write in ASCII format (default)
         -b  write in Matlab binary format
```

https://www.j-raedler.de/projects/DyMat/ can be used to read the result-file and generate a file on any format you like (using Python).

OpenModelica has an option similar to `alist` that can also resample the signal if you want fewer data points https://openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/v1.12.0/scripting_api.html#filtersimulationresults.

Comment: `alist.exe -e inertia1.w -e inertia2.w PID_Controller.mat PID_Controller.csv` extracts two variables from the .mat result file and stores it as .csv