# Export Modelica variables in MAT files with no post-processing

Tags: modelica

The purpose here is to:

- output some specific variables in a MAT file (without the complex structure offered by the standard Modelica output);
- without any post-processing i.e. after the simulation I'd like to have the MAT file ready-to-go, with no further steps (contrary to [Writing specific variable to .txt or .mat with Dymola](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52611665/writing-specific-variable-to-txt-or-mat-with-dymola));
- not IDE specific (not using Dymola or OpenModelica specific commands);
- *potentially* without generating events;

The `Modelica.Utilities.Streams.writeRealMatrix` utility is what came to my mind at first, but I cannot make the `append` argument to work properly.

Here is what I tried:

```
model WriteRealMatrixToFileTest
  discrete Boolean success;
  discrete Real time_pre(start=0, fixed=true);

equation 
  when sample(0,0.1) then
    success = Modelica.Utilities.Streams.writeRealMatrix("OutMat.mat", "OutMat", {{time, sin(time)}}, append=true, format="4");
    Modelica.Utilities.Streams.print("Printing status at time " + String(time) + ": " + String(success));
    time_pre = time;
  end when;
end WriteRealMatrixToFileTest;
```

but, even though it always return succesfull and even if the command is correctly called at every 0.1s, in the MAT file I just find the very last value (e.g. {10, -0.544} if stopTime=10).

One option would be to reading back the MAT file, append the new set of values to the matrix, re-write them back again, but it sounds really ugly to me. Are there other ways?
Since I cannot declare a dynamic-size matrix I cannot think of other options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The append argument works, but it does not behave like you expect. `writeRealMatrix` appends variables to the given `.mat` file, but it does not append values to an existing matrix inside this file. If a variable with this name exists, it is overwritten.

And idea would be to:

- Continuously write the results to a `.txt` file via `Modelica.Utilities.Streams.print`, which automatically appends to existing files
- At the end of the simulation read the `.txt` content and store it with `writeRealMatrix` as `.mat` file inside a `when terminal()` section

Maybe like this:

```
model WriteRealMatrixToFileTest
  import Modelica.Utilities.Streams;
  import Modelica.Utilities.Strings;

  Boolean success(start=false);

  parameter String tmpFile = "OutMat.txt";
  parameter String outFile = "OutMat.mat";

protected 
  function txt2mat "Convert txt file to mat file"
    input String inFile;
    input String outFile;
    output Boolean success;

  protected 
    String[:] lines;
    Integer nlines;
    Real t[:], v[:];
    Integer pos "Start position of value at current line";

  algorithm 
    lines :=Streams.readFile(inFile);
    nlines :=size(lines, 1);
    t :=fill(0, nlines); // we have to initialize t and v with the correct size
    v :=fill(0, nlines); // so we can later use t[i] and v[i]

    for i in 1:nlines loop
      t[i] :=Strings.scanReal(lines[i], 1);
      pos :=Strings.find(lines[i], ";")+1; // get delimiter position to scan v
      v[i] :=Strings.scanReal(lines[i], pos);
    end for;

    success :=Streams.writeRealMatrix(outFile,"OutMat",{t,v},format="4");
  end txt2mat;


equation 
  when initial() then
    Modelica.Utilities.Files.removeFile(tmpFile);
  end when;

  when sample(0,0.1) then
    Streams.print(String(time)+";"+String(sin(time)), fileName=tmpFile);
  end when;

  when terminal() then
    success = txt2mat(tmpFile, outFile);
  end when;
end WriteRealMatrixToFileTest;
```